# wp7 webbrowser navigating event not triggered

Tags: windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

I have a webpage with a hyperlink "myapp://mypage?id=123456&name=hello" , clicking the link is supposed to trigger the webbrowser Navigating event so that I can catch the url and do something meaningful. The problem here is that the Navigating event is not triggered at all.
I tried  normal website eg: "http://xxxx.com" and it works. So is there a way to deal with user custom urls with webbrowser control?
ps: IsScriptEnabled is True
thanks

Comment: Have you got an example as it might be something specific to your set up.

Answer (score 0):

From my investigation into this, WebBrowser.Navigating only gets called if you attempt a hyperlink when using the file, http and mailto protocols. Custom protocols are not even served.

Digging around the web for custom extensions leads me to believe that it is possible to implement something that works around it, but doing so would be a great deal of headache and pain.

If you do/did find anything, please post it, as I would be interested to see your solution.